# Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #[object HTMLElement] Error

Tags: jquery

I made a Overlay section with jQuery.

This i call with `<a href="javascript:slide(cms);">`.
But i get this error:

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #[object HTMLElement]
>   [http://localhost//js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js:4]

Any idea? Here's the slide method:

```
function slide(content) {
    $('#' + content).show(0);
    $('#' + content).animate({
        left: '0%'
    }, 500);
}
$('.c-close').click(function(){ 
    $('.slide').animate({
        left: '100%'
    }, 500);
    $('.slide').hide(0);
});
```

Comment: How are you calling it?

Comment: @letiagoalves `cms.toString()` is obviously `[object HTMLElement]`. So either it's an element, or it's the product of another bug.

Comment: It's a id of a section

Comment: So you should do `<a href="javascript:slide('cms');">`

Comment: cms is an ID, which the javascript will automatically fetch with getElementByID when used as variable name.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`content.toString()` is `[object HTMLElement]`. So `content` is an element (or the product of another bug in the part of the code we don't see).

As `content` is an element, not its id, you should use `$(content)`, not `$('#'+content)`.

Comment: It is not really a good solution because Karen sends the id to the slide function. In this case because the ID is not sent as string, javascript selects the matching tag with ID. If Karen wants to use this solution, she must be sure not sending an ID and trusting automatically DOM selection. But send a DOM element.

Comment: Well I mean it's a great solution, but Karen must know not so send the Element id, but a real element in stead.

Answer (score 3):

The right answer depends on what content and cms is.

You send cms because your element has an id with the name "cms"

If content is an DOM element identifier you should make sure that Id is passed as a string.

```
<div id="cms" ></div>
<a href="javascript:slide('cms');">
```

And rename your function so its more clear what it does:

```
function slide(element_id) {
    $('#' + element_id).show(0);
    $('#' + element_id).animate({
        left: '0%'
    }, 500);
}
```

There are some other solutions:

If cms is a previously set variable containing a DOm element.

For example.

Javascript:

```
var cms = $('cms');

function slide(content) {
    content.show(0);
    content.animate({
        left: '0%'
    }, 500);
}
```

OR:

```
var cms = document.getElementById("cms");

function slide(content) {
    $(content).show(0);
    $(content).animate({
        left: '0%'
    }, 500);
}
```

html:

```
<a href="javascript:slide(cms);">.
```

Depending on what you want.

Remember if you use @dystroy his solution which is very good, not to simply send the element id as a variable. But actually send the dom element post-selection.

My solution would be:

```
<div id="cms"></div>
<a href="#" id="slide">slide</a>
<script>
    (function(){
        $('slide').on('click',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var slideElement = $('div#cms');
            slideElement.show(0);
            slideElement.animate({
                left: '0%'
            }, 500);
        });
    })();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To use a variable in a jQuery selector, it should be a string.
So surround your **cms** with ' --> `<a href="javascript:slide('cms');">`

Comment: Use dystroy his solution! it's better!